# How can I import my objects file in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an .js file where I have my books as bellow:

```
export const booksData = [
{
    id: "1",
    title: "1491",
    description: "A fantastic historical book",
    genre: 'Historical',
    image: "https://shop.radical-guide.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/1491-Front.jpg"
},
```

How can I import and display these books dynamically in my react application?

Comment: `import { booksData } from "path/to/file.js"`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"dynamically"_? Do you expect the data in this `.js` file to change? If so, when and how does it change? If not, you can simply bundle it by importing it as above

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import { booksData } from "path/to/file.js"
```

You don't really need to pass it as a prop. Only if you are using a component, then yes, you should, eg:

```
<Component books={booksData} />
```

Then, in the Component function you pass it as a prop.

```
function Component(props){
    return (
     <>
         {
           props.books.map(book => {
            return(
           <h1>{book.title}</h1>
         )})}
    </>
)}
```

If not, you can directly import to the component that object(not recommended)

```
import { booksData } from "path/to/file.js"
```

And simply:

```
function Component(){

    return (
     <>
         {
           booksData.map(book => {
            return(
           <h1>{book.title}</h1>
         )})}
    </>
)}
```

Comment: Don't forget to add key props. `key={book.id}` would be my pick

Answer (score -2):

**//   First of All You Need to import your .js file like that**

import booksData from '/path/to/file.js'

Comment: Then you have need to use props method

Comment: It's a named export and props isn't a method.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).